# Cometd Sweeps Session after Client Subscribed to Channel

Tags: java, spring, cometd

Cometd sweeps session immediately after the the client subscribed to the persistent channel

log message:
 Client 41mpv6rfh63ij316pphziifnmsj subscribed to  Channel ::/notification
2014-02-19 11:05:19,010 [BayeuxServer@1449984133]  DEBUG  [org.cometd.bayeux.server.ServerSession sweep] - Sweeping session 41mpv6rfh63ij316pphziifnmsj - last connect 1392825919011 ms ago

Channel is marked as persistent

```
@Configure("/notification")
public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel)
{
    channel.setPersistent(true);// channel persistent
    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL);   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The log is vastly incomplete and without timing information, but in principle if a session is subscribed to a channel then it can be swept any moment.

Sessions are swept if there is no communication with the client, which is independent from whether they are or not subscribed to any channel.

Comment: As long as the channel is persistent.. it shouldn't be swept Correct?

Comment: Sure, as long as the channel is persistent, the _channel_ will not be swept. But the session will if the conditions for sweeping the session are met, and these are independent from channels.